# Linking configuration

Tags: 2013, configuration, linking

I have the following setup in the `cd_link_conf.xml` and links are resolving as expected.

```
<Host Domain="example.com" Port="" Path="/websitefolder/"/>
```

Another domain will be introduced soon, serving the same website (lets call it example2.com), and links need to resolve relatively to the visitor domain.

For example, if visitor is on example.com links need to point to `http://example.com/websitefolder/page1.aspx` and if visitor is on example2.com links need to point to `http://example2.com/websitefolder/page1.aspx`

I have tried the following configuration

```
<Host Domain="" Port="" Path="/websitefolder/"/>
```

but it didn't solve my problem, as it didn't produce a relative link, instead I got `http://websitefolder/page1.aspx`.

```
<Host Domain="/" Port="" Path="/websitefolder/"/>
```

produced the same result.

How can I setup linking relative to the visitor domain, with settings for Path active ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave the `Publications` element completely empty, you will get relative linking, as soon as you add a `Publication` with a `Host` element, you will get an absolute link to that.

So try this:

```
<Publications>
    <!--
    <Publication Id="1">
        <Host Domain="example.com" Protocol="http" Port="80" Path="/websitefolder/"/>
    </Publication>
    -->
</Publications>
```

No this might mean you need to set the path `websitefolder` in your Publication properties.

Comment: Hi Bart, I can not add websitefolder to the publication properties as this is not an actual folder on the file system and that would case deployment problems. Is it possible to have a Path parameter without having a hardcoded domain?

Comment: @user3760419 Have you tried the Publication URL, when you choose the Publication Path it will physically go there indeed, but when you use Publication URL, its only part of the URL.

Comment: Hi Bart, I completely forgot about the url property. This solved my problem.